# Accidental deletion of webform

Tags: webform-civicrm, delete

We accidentally deleted a webform and we'd like to retrieve it. Is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of drupal question rather than CiviCRM. I would restore it from db backup.

1. Create a test instance and import the database from backup
2. Export the webform using [node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module from test instance
3. Import the exported file on live using [node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module.
4. For importing submissions you can export the submission form test instance and user [webform import](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_import) module to import on live.